# After override UICollectionViewFlowLayout it shows logging only once for a cache mismatched frame

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, ios9.2

After I override `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` it show 3 warning like below

- Logging only once for UICollectionViewFlowLayout cache mismatched frame
- `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` has cached frame mismatch for index path  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1} - cached value: {{145, 0}, {130, 130}}; expected value: {{5, 141}, {130, 130}}
- This is likely occurring because the flow layout subclass FullyHorizontalFlowLayout is modifying attributes returned by `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` without copying them

i use '`FullyHorizontalFlowLayout`' to make i cell arrange from left to right (original is from top to bottom). below is my '`layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`' code

```
-(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGFloat newX = MIN(0, rect.origin.x - rect.size.width/2);
CGFloat newWidth = rect.size.width*2 + (rect.origin.x - newX);

CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(newX, rect.origin.y, newWidth, rect.size.height);

// Get all the attributes for the elements in the specified frame
NSArray *allAttributesInRect = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:newRect];

for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr in allAttributesInRect) {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *newAttr = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:attr.indexPath];

    attr.frame = newAttr.frame;

    attr.center = newAttr.center;
    attr.bounds = newAttr.bounds;
    attr.hidden = newAttr.hidden;
    attr.size = newAttr.size;

}
return allAttributesInRect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the support Attributes array deeply with the fragment below:

```
NSArray *superArray = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:superArray copyItems:YES];
```